# Why Session is getting lost every-time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Update:

If I refresh my page then it does get the data from Session and I have a postback through submit or onchange then it losses the Session

here is my cod that onchange event

> onchange = "document.location.href = '/Home/Employee?c=' +
>   this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" }

```
<div class="col-xs-5">
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewBag.DropDownName, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", onchange = "document.location.href = '/Home/Employee?c=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
</div>
```

I have no idea why my Session is getting lost and everytime it postback the page it seems that loosing the session to null.... what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public static class SessionHelper  
    {
        public static void StoreSessionHomeIndexViewModel(HomeIndexViewModel list)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("HomeIndexViewModel", list);
        }

        public static HomeIndexViewModel GetSessionHomeIndexViewModel()
        {
            return ((HomeIndexViewModel)HttpContext.Current.Session["HomeIndexViewModel"]);
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
private HomeIndexViewModel LoadData()
        {
            var vModel = new HomeIndexViewModel();
            if (SessionHelper.GetSessionHomeIndexViewModel() == null)
            {
                vModel = new HomeIndexViewModel { Employee = _db.CEmployee.ToList() };            
                SessionHelper.StoreSessionHomeIndexViewModel(vModel);
            }
            else
            {
                vModel = SessionHelper.GetSessionHomeIndexViewModel();
            } 
            return vModel;
        }
```

Comment: I have used `ViewBag` same issue, so what should i use then?

Comment: can you check session timeout  in both IIS and web.config

Comment: From where are you calling `LoadData()`. For instance, are you calling it in an action method or in the controller's constructor?

Comment: What web server are you using? IIS? IIS Express? Web Matrix?

Comment: i'm using iis express

Comment: What method are you using for sessions? Cookies? Uri? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Are you using Uri based sessions?

If you are, then see the bottom of the answer for a quick-and-dirty solution (or read on for the full explanation.)

The only thing that I can think of, is that you're using the `Uri` to save the session like this. If you are, the url will look something like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/(S(rzibneny21box4rtmi))/Home/Employee
```

If that's what you're doing, then when you submit the form or change the `document.location`, you will loose the session id, unless you do something to preserve the `(S(rzibneny21box4rtmi))` part of the Uri. That part of the Uri is the session id.

The above would explain why a simple page refresh preserves the session while overwriting the `document.location` does not. If you overwrite the `document.location`, you'll lose the session id.

## Example: Works with Cookie Session (not Uri Sessions)

I've updated my answer based on your use of the `onchange` event. It works on my machine if I'm using cookies for session but  NOT if I set `cookieless` to `true`.

In the example, I tried to emulate your `select` list, though mine turns out differently than yours did. That's because I wasn't sure of your view model's structure. It's probably good enough for the examples sake.

### View

In the view, I've include both a submit button and an `onclick` event that changes the `document.location`. Both work as expected with the cookie sessions (but not with uri sessions.)

With cookies, the new `Employee` appears in the `select` list and the number of employees increments as expected.

```
@model WebApp.Models.HomeIndexViewModel

<form action="~/Home/Employee">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>
            m.FirstName,
            new SelectList(Model.Employees, "FirstName", "LastName"),
            new { onchange = "document.location.href = '/Home/Employee?c=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
    <label>Number of Employees @Model.Employees.Count</label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

### Model

I wasn't sure of your view model's structure, so I created one like this for the purposes of the example.

```
namespace WebApp.Models
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class HomeIndexViewModel
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }

        public List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>() {
            new Employee() { FirstName = "FirstName0", LastName = "LastName0" },
            new Employee() { FirstName = "FirstName1", LastName = "LastName1" }
        };

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Controller

For the example's sake, the `Employee` action method just adds a new `Employee` object to the collection and returns the `Index` view.

```
namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Models;
    using Helpers;

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = LoadData();
            return View(model);
        }

        public ActionResult Employee(string FirstName)
        {
            var model = LoadData();
            return View("Index", model);
        }

        private HomeIndexViewModel LoadData()
        {
            var vModel = new HomeIndexViewModel();
            if (SessionHelper.GetSessionHomeIndexViewModel() == null)
            {
                vModel = new HomeIndexViewModel();
                SessionHelper.StoreSessionHomeIndexViewModel(vModel);
            }
            else
            {
                vModel = SessionHelper.GetSessionHomeIndexViewModel();
                var count = vModel.Employees.Count;
                vModel.Employees.Add(new HomeIndexViewModel.Employee()
                {
                    FirstName = string.Format("FirstName{0}", count),
                    LastName = string.Format("LastName{0}", count)
                });
            }

            return vModel;
        }
    }
}
```

### Helper

The is essentially the same helper that you had in the original question.

```
namespace WebApp.Helpers
{
    using System.Web;
    using Models;

    public static class SessionHelper
    {
        public static void StoreSessionHomeIndexViewModel(HomeIndexViewModel list)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("HomeIndexViewModel", list);
        }

        public static HomeIndexViewModel GetSessionHomeIndexViewModel()
        {
            return ((HomeIndexViewModel)HttpContext.Current.Session["HomeIndexViewModel"]);
        }
    }
}
```

The above only works when my session uses cookies. If the `system.web` section of the web.config has `cookieless="true"`, then the above example does not work, because the form submission and/or the update of `document.location.href` do not preserve the `(S(rzibneny21box4rtmi))` part of the Uri and thereby do not preserve the session.

## Example: Works with Uri Sessions!

If you are using Uri session, you must set either the `form.action` or `document.location` in a way that preserves the session id. For instance, here is something I just hacked together. It works on my machine with cookieless sessions.

```
@model WebApp.Models.HomeIndexViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {

        // get the domain plus the session id

        var index = document.location.toString().lastIndexOf(")");
        var sub = document.location.toString().substring(0, index + 1);

        // using that as the base url
        // set the form action & onchange event

        document.getElementById("myForm").action = sub + "/";
        document.getElementById("mySelect").onchange = function () {
            document.location.href 
                = sub 
                + "/Home/Employee?c=" 
                + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
        };
    };

</script>

<form id="myForm" action="">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m =>
            m.FirstName,
            new SelectList(Model.Employees, "FirstName", "LastName"),
            new { id = "mySelect" })
    <label>Number of Employees @Model.Employees.Count</label>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This now works as expected, because the `form.action` and the `onclick` include the session id in the request Uri. Are you using cookieless sessions?

Comment: i have in my web.config ` <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>`

Comment: Does your browser support cookies? Try also setting `cookieless="true"` to see if that's the problem.

Comment: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp/session to check if IIS is the culprit

Comment: 1+ thanks for your effort but have you tried posting back the page and see if it still holding the session?

Comment: what I have noticed that if I just refresh the browser it gets the data from session and if I have a postback then it loses the session, please see my updated code

Comment: @AbuHamzah - MVC doesn't really have the notion of postbacks, unlike web forms.  What are you POSTing in your example?

Comment: I'm aware of that but I was trying to give  the context of my problem and I'm doing onchange event please have a look at my question `onchange = "document.location.href = '/Home/Employee?c=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" }`